# Codeigniter count associated records between 2 tables

Tags: php, database, codeigniter, join, count

I have 2 database tables 'super_admin_staff' and 'super_admin_roles'

The staff table is made up like :

```
id
name
email
phone
role
```

The role table is made up like :

```
id
role
```

The id column from the roles table is unique and is associated with the 'roles' column of the staff table.

At the moment i am fetching all the roles from the database using model :

```
 function superAdminStaffRoles()
{
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('super_admin_roles');


    $query = $this->db->get();

    $result = $query->result();
    return $result;


}
```

In my controller i pass it over to my view like this :

```
public function superAdminStaffRoles()
{
    if ($this->isSuperAdmin() != true) {
        $this->loadThis();
    } else {
        $this->load->model('super_admin_staff_model');

        $data['userRecords'] = $this->super_admin_staff_model->superAdminStaffRoles();

        $this->global['pageTitle'] = 'Staff Roles';
        $this->global['pageDesc'] = 'Add or Edit new Staff Roles and Permissions';

        $this->loadViews("super_admin/staff_roles", $this->global, $data, null);
    }
}
```

then display the data in my view like :

```
<tbody>
      <?php
      if (!empty($userRecords)) {
        foreach ($userRecords as $record) {
          ?>
          <tr>


            <td><?php echo $record->role ?></td>
            <td>where want to loop through the association</td>
            <td class="text-center">

              <a class="btn btn-sm btn-info" href="<?php echo base_url() ?>/EditRole/<?php echo $record->id; ?>"><i class="fas fa-edit"></i></a>
              <a class="btn btn-sm btn-danger deleteUser" href="<?php echo base_url() ?>/DeleteRole/<?php echo $record->id; ?>"><i class="fas fa-trash"></i></a>
            </td>
          </tr>
      <?php
        }
      }
      ?>

    </tbody>
```

How can i fetch the additional information i need in my model to display how many staff are associated with that role? i think i may need to join the tables and i don't have much knowledge on joins.

can it be done in the same query?

the result should be something like :

```
Staff table

|id  | name    | role |
.......................
|1   | staff1  | 1    |
|2   | staff2  | 1    |
|3   | staff3  | 2    |
|4   | staff4  | 3    |
|5   | staff5  | 3    |

Role Table

|id  | role   |
...............
|1   | role 1 |
|2   | role 2 |
|3   | role 3 |
```

and the result should look like :

```
|Staff Role | Assigned |
........................
| Role1     | 2        |
| Role2     | 1        |
| Role3     | 2        |
```

Any help appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go

First, you need to join the two tables

**INNER JOIN**

```
$this->db->from('super_admin_staff');
$this->db->join('super_admin_roles', 'super_admin_staff.role = super_admin_roles.id');
```

You'll get the following

```
|id  | name    | role |id  | role   |
......................................
|1   | staff1  | 1    |1   | role 1 |
|2   | staff2  | 1    |1   | role 1 |
|3   | staff3  | 2    |2   | role 2 |
|4   | staff4  | 3    |3   | role 3 |
|5   | staff5  | 3    |3   | role 3 |
```

**LEFT JOIN**

```
$this->db->from('super_admin_staff');
$this->db->join('super_admin_roles', 'super_admin_staff.role = super_admin_roles.id', 'left');
```

You'll get the following

```
|id  | name    | role |id  | role   |
......................................
|1   | staff1  | 1    |1   | role 1 |
|2   | staff2  | 1    |1   | role 1 |
|3   | staff3  | 2    |2   | role 2 |
|4   | staff4  | 3    |3   | role 3 |
|5   | staff5  | 3    |3   | role 3 |
|6   | staff6  | 0    |null| null   |
```

**GROUP BY**

Then grouping (which is strongly associated with the select because what is in the select clause MUST be in the group by).
Here you want to group by the role, you can do by grouping with super_admin_staff.role, super_admin_roles.id or super_admin_roles.role.
As you want the super_admin_roles.role in the output, let's take it as grouping column.

Using COUNT(*) will return the number of rows for each group.

```
$this->db->select('super_admin_roles.role as StaffRole, COUNT(*) as Assigned');    
$this->db->from('super_admin_staff');
$this->db->join('super_admin_roles', 'super_admin_staff.role = super_admin_roles.id');
$this->db->group_by('super_admin_roles.role');
$query = $this->db->get();
```

Comment: How do i then access the information? by changing my model code to the code you supplied it no longer uses the variables i have in the foreach loop in my view throwing an Undefined property: stdClass error for each variable. at the moment i return the query as `$data['userRecords']` then for each loop as `$record` then access each database column like `$record->role` or `$record->id` etc

Comment: It's ok i figured it out i didnt know i should be using StaffRole and Assigned to access the data. after re-reading your answer it clicked when you said the group is strongly associated with the select. I also needed the id from the roles table so i added `super_admin_roles.id as role_id` into the select as well. Thank you

Comment: Now i have the problem that if there is no associated staff it does not display the role at all. is there a way to allow it to have a role with 0 displayed if no staff have been assigned?

Comment: You need to do a LEFT JOIN instead of an INNER JOIN (what is actually in my answer). To do this you need to add a parameter 'left' to the join method : `$this->db->join('super_admin_roles', 'super_admin_staff.role = super_admin_roles.id', 'left');` [here is some documentation about SQL joins](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp)